# Is there a way to know how often a file was downloaded from my public Dropbox folder?

Tags: dropbox, download, statistics

I often put files in my public Dropbox folder and send the public link to people by email. Is there a way to get some sort of report of how often files were accessed? Or is it possible to know the number of downloads?

Comment: Closed due to this change in Dropbox policy: https://www.dropbox.com/help/files-folders/public-folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At present (February 2011) this is not possible to do in Dropbox. It is on the [wish list though](https://www.dropbox.com/votebox/14/analytics-statistics-for-public-files).

Comment: Thank you for the link! I've added some of my votes to it. :) for all who also are intested in this feature: please vote it up on Dropbox.

Comment: @Barry - do you know if there has been any change in this (seeing as this was 3 years ago)

Comment: @sam - nope no changes to Dropbox on this front.  They still require that you use a third party tool like  http://orangedox.com/dropbox  or http://bit.ly

Answer (score 6):

You could use a URL shortener (such as bit.ly or goo.gl) to create a link to the Dropbox public link and get the stats from the URL shortener service.

Comment: If your file is a .exe file (and maybe other types), bit.ly will warn the user that the file 'is potentially dangerous', which may stop your user from downloading the file. I myself distrust sites that make you download a .exe file without giving you the file extension in the link (like a shortened url), so I decided not to use bit.ly for that, I will have to zip the .exe an re-upload the file.

Answer (score 1):

we've just released a beta version of our Dropbox plugin for Orangedox which does lets you monitor the number of times your dropbox files have been downloaded.

http://orangedox.com/dropbox

Feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Update .. we're now out of beta and also include the ability to track previews vs downloads for files within shared folders

Comment: The basic plan doesn't allow custom URLs to be created, which makes it useless for me. Bit.ly, on the other hand, does.

Comment: Yep that's correct Igor, our basic plan does not but our pro plan does. You can get a 14 day free trial to test it out.