# Who has downloaded my offered files already?

Tags: dropbox, download, statistics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to know how often a file was downloaded from my public Dropbox folder?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12705/is-there-a-way-to-know-how-often-a-file-was-downloaded-from-my-public-dropbox-fo)

I offered some people in my family to download files via Dropbox.

How do I know once they have done so?

Comment: how did you "offer" them?

Comment: if by "offer" you mean by a share link then yes Dropbox doesn't (still) allow for this. However you can wrap your share links using http://bit.ly or our plugin for Dropbox http://orangedox.com/dropbox

Answer (score 3):

There [currently isn't any feature](https://www.dropbox.com/votebox/14/analytics-statistics-for-public-files) to show statistics regarding the number of downloads a file has, but there are workarounds that you can do.

If you have shared the whole folder, then it is not possible, but if you only shared links to specific files, you can use the bit.ly URL shortener to keep visit statistics for you. The question is of course how you "offer" those files to your family.